# Why does my email have random hyperlinks where there are none?

Tags: yahoo-mail, links

Just to elaborate on that, I typed out an email on Word and copied it to Yahoo Mail and I noticed that one paragraph had been hyperlinked automatically! There isn't supposed to be a hyperlink there! So, I deleted the text and typed it out again on Yahoo Mail and there was that hyperlink again. This happened several times, but eventually it allowed me to type it without a hyperlink. But after sending it, the same paragraph was hyperlinked again!

I tried clicking the link and it doesn't go anywhere. I tried copying the email text to Word and editing the hyperlink, but it just showed me that the link was empty.

I tried opening it on my Android phone - tapping the link opened a blank chrome tab, but long-pressing the link gave me this `x-thread://-76874911/10984`

There is no reason for the software to assume that it is a link. The entire para is just plain text, like "Once upon a time, email got weird etc. etc."

Any idea what that is? Or why some random text on my email got hyperlinked?

Comment: You didn't tell us what the text was, or even what format, so we've nothing to work with

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh sorry about that. I had no idea where to start with this question, so didn't know what would help! Well, the text is a little confidential, but what do you mean by format?

Comment: I mean you don't need to put the exact text, but we need to know if you wrote 'fred bloggs went shopping' or 'something://some text' - the first would be odd, the second a perfect reason for the software to assume a link

Comment: Ah, OK. it was just plain text, similar to your first example 'fred bloggs went shopping'. No reason for the software to assume a link. The strangest part is that the link begins at a random point on the first line of the para and ends at a random point near the last line of the para.
I've edited the question to address this, thanks! :)

Comment: Best guess then would be that something Word is doing in the original text is carrying RTF elements with it, which the emailer is misinterpreting as RTF/HTML. Try first copy/pasting to a purely plain-text environment, then re-copy/paste to email. The plain text will either show up the RTF elements so you can see them, or it will discard them completely.

Comment: It is possible there is malware on your system. There are certain malware who will automatically create advertisement links to certain words.

Comment: It might be interpreting it as an address? It might do that if it contains a number, and/or something that looks like a street/road name. It would probably still help if you can post the actual text, or find something similar that causes the same effect if you're concerned about privacy.

Comment: @Tetsujin Copying to a plain text environment and then back again seems to have worked! If you could post your comment as an answer, I could mark it as the best. Just to note, tested both through Yahoo Mail and Outlook. Sending from Yahoo mail was fine, but sending from Outlook had the whole para underlined.

Comment: At the moment even though it worked it would be a partial answer - I'd love to know what Word thought it ought to be copying that it shouldn't. Do you have any other plaintext environments you could test that might possibly show up the RTF when you paste in? It would make the final answer so much more complete.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. @Tetsujin Do you have any suggestions for what I could use to show the RTF? I tried it on Word itself, Yahoo, Sublime Text and NotePad - all of which either removed the RTF or displayed a link.

Comment: I don't, tbh, I'm not on Windows myself. One last test would be to paste a 'cleaned' version back into Word & see if it's actually making this up as it goes along, or whether it could have misinterpreted some earlier formatting etc. I'll try to cobble together something of an actual answer, as we've found the fix, if not the cause.

Comment: That's actually how I tested it before, @Tetsujin . I pasted the 'cleaned' text back into the Word doc and copied the entire word doc into Yahoo. Everything worked fine!

Comment: OK, I've thrown in an answer based on what we've discovered. Perhaps some else might come along later to provide a satisfactory *'why'* ;)

Comment: Alright! I accepted the answer, since it solved the issue. But as you said, hopefully someone comes by and posts why :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guesswork answer, based on the Q&A in comments. Feel free to add further detail if anyone knows how this may have happened.

My initial guess was that Word had some invisible embedded RTF instructions or similar, that it was carrying over in the copy/paste.

Experimentation has proven this to be the most likely explanation - though the 'why' remains elusive.

The 'simple fix' is to copy/paste from Word into any app that can only handle plaintext, then copy/paste back again, based on the theory that the 'RTF' data would either be exposed by this method, or discarded entirely.

This appears to be totally successful.

However, as the extra data causing the issue seems to be completely discarded in the copy via plaintext, I can't figure out exactly what is was that caused the issue.